# rails 4 crash report size on console, too long how to reduce size?

Tags: debugging, ruby-on-rails-4

Running rails 4.0.3, in development mode, the crash report in console is quite big ...

A lot of lines, the most interesting being at the beginning

Is there anyway way to parameter the size of the crash debugger log?

Comment: are you talking about the stacktrace?

Comment: yes,  under dev, using Webrick , in the console when crashing or if I hit ctrl-C, to shutdown the server, I get full crash report  (  Crash Report log information, Control frame information, C level backtrace information, Other runtime information , with all loaded features ... => 200 lines , full gem files... )

Comment: this is the default way to print a stacktrace and you want to have that because it might contain the relevant debugging information

Comment: another thing. if you ask for help, always provide meaningful examples of what you are talking about to give context.